# Evaluating $\int xy \ d(xy)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

In the "Integrating Factors" section of an old introductory differential equations book, this example problem is presented:
$$\frac{x \ dy-y \ dx}{x^2}=xy \ (x \ dy+y \ dx)$$
$$d \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)=xy \ d(xy) \quad (*)$$
The book then simply says, "Integrate," and shows the answer: $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1}{2} \ x^2y^2+k$.

I'm puzzled by the right side of equation (*) though. Integrating it would produce an integral of the form $\int xy \ d(xy)$, which is new to me.  I'm familiar with differentials and iterated integrals, but I've never seen an integral with two variables simultaneously in a $d( \ )$ expression *with* variables preceding the $d( \ )$.

The left-hand side of (*) is easy: an integral of a differentiated function is simply the function itself (plus a constant).

But for the right side, can I just treat $(xy)$ as some sort of unit and integrate, since it's followed by $d(xy)$?
$$\int xy \ d(xy)= \frac{1}{2}(xy)^2=\frac{1}{2}x^2y^2$$
That just seems too simplistic, especially since two variables are being multiplied together.  I'd expect it to require something akin to integration by parts.

Yet, if I do the following (which seems more legitimate), I get a wrong answer for the right-hand side:
$$\int xy \ d(xy)= \int xy \ (x \ dy+y \ dx) = \int (x^2y \ dy \ + \ xy^2dx)$$
$$=x^2\frac{y^2}{2}+y^2\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{2x^2y^2}{2}=x^2y^2 \ + \ k$$
I don't think the discrepancy can be resolved simply by saying the constants are different.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You cannot conclude from the first line the second line in the derivation that seems to be more legitimate. The reason is that $x$, and $y$ are not independent of each other, so $x$ is not a constant when you integrate over $y$ and the other way round. For the first integral, just perform a substitution $z=xy$...

Comment: Oh!  Yes, if y is a function of x, then that "more legitimate" way is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you find it more in the spirit of integrating factors when you notice that the right hand side can be written as $d( x^2 y^2/2)= xy (x dy + y dx)$.

Comment: Wow... I don't know if I'd have ever seen that relationship.

Comment: I'm confused... The "more legitimate" (actually illegitimate) method I proposed is wrong because it would actually yield something like $\left(\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+C_1(x)\right)+\left(\frac{y^2x^2}{2}+C_2(y)\right)$, which wouldn't give a clear answer, because the constants aren't simple constants.  Is that correct?

Comment: Ah... Based on Hurkyl's post, this partial antiderivative process can't be fused like this.  If done distinctly (as the end of Hurkyl's post shows), the correct answer is again generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the wonderful things about differentials (as opposed to, say, partial derivatives) is that they don't care about independent/dependent variables, interact extremely well with algebraic manipulations, and so forth.

For example, you know that $\mathrm{d}\left( \frac{1}{2} t^2 \right) = t \, \mathrm{d}t$, and if we have $t = xy$ then it immediately follows that $\mathrm{d}\left( \frac{1}{2} (xy)^2 \right) = xy \, \mathrm{d} xy$. Thus, $\frac{1}{2}(xy)^2$ is an antiderivative of $xy \, \mathrm{d}xy$.

And this fact is true always; when $x$ and $y$ are: independent, dependent on each other, dependent on additional variables, or even constant!

Now, an important point that you've overlooked is, just as there is a difference between the differential $\mathrm{d}$ and partial derivatives, there is a difference between the 'antidifferential' and the partial antiderivatives.

When you calculated $\int x^2 y\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{2} x^2y^2$,  you computed a *partial* antiderivative. That is, you antidifferentiated subject to the constrant that $x$ is held constant. This is no good, since you were trying to invert the differential, not a partial derivative!

The same happens if you consider definite integration instead of indefinite integration — the appropriate integral would be a *path integral* $\int_\gamma x^2 y \, \mathrm{d} y $, where $\gamma$ is a path restricted to the one-dimensional space of allowed values of $(x,y)$. Arbitrary paths in the plane are disallowed  — such as the vertical paths that would be analogous to the partial antiderivative in $y$.

---

Now, partial antidifferentiation can be used to compute an antidifferential. If $x$ and $y$ are independent variables and $z$ a scalar depending on them, then

$$ \mathrm{d} z = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \mathrm{d} x +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \mathrm{d} y $$

(where, as usual, $\partial/\partial x$ means to hold $y$ constant and vice versa)

So, if an antidifferential exists, we can get information from partial antiderivatives; e.g.
$$ \int \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \mathrm{d} x = z + c(y) $$
(where, as usual, $\int \ldots \mathrm{d}x$ means the partial antiderivative while holding $y$ constant) Then, if the solution is not obvious, take the differential again (or just take the partial derivative in $y$) to get a differential equation you can solve for $c(y)$.

For example, in the given problem, if we define $z$ be such that
$$ \mathrm{d}z = x^2 y \, \mathrm{d}y + x y^2 \, \mathrm{d}x $$
then in the generic domain where $x$ and $y$ are independent, the partial antiderivatives in $y$ and $x$ you computed imply, respectively,
$$ z = \frac{x^2 y^2}{2} + C_1(x) $$
$$ z = \frac{x^2 y^2}{2} + C_2(y) $$
at which point the general solution is clear:
$$ z = \frac{x^2 y^2}{2} + C $$
And as before, since the equation
$$ \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{x^2 y^2}{2} + C\right) = x^2 y \, \mathrm{d}y + x y^2 \, \mathrm{d}x $$
holds when $x$ and $y$ are independent, it holds always.

Comment: @ Hurkyl: Beautiful explanation -- on a level *I* can understand.  One question: should it be "define dz such that $dz=x^2y \ dy \ +\ xy^2 \ dx$?

Comment: @DBS: It should be "define $z$ such that $\mathrm{d} z = \ldots$. I've made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do this:

1. Make the substitution $u = xy$.
2. Then the integral becomes $\int u\, du$.

That should be easy enough to solve, then just "de-substitute" u as xy.

After doing some thinking, I decided to substitute $d(xy)$ as $$(y + xy')dx.
\tag{1}$$
Then, substituting (1) back into the original integral, we get $$\int xy^2 + x^2yy'.$$
Any hints on how to evaluate this?

Comment: The u=xy substition makes sense and fits with Fabian's comment above.  The second method would proceed using the partial antiderivative method discussed by Hurkyl.